# C++ alternative to params object[] in C#

Tags: c++

Hello Guys so i want to code something in C++ that i have for C# but as there is no params object in C++ i need some help :P

Ok, so here's what i want to do:

```
static Int32 Procedure(UInt32 address, params Object[] parameters)
{
    Int32 length = parameters.Length;
    Int32 index = 0;
    UInt32 count = 0;
    UInt32 Strings = 0;
    UInt32 Single = 0;
    UInt32 Array = 0;
    while (index < length)
    {
        if (parameters[index] is Int32)
        {
            WriteInt32(0x10050000 + (count * 4), (Int32)parameters[index]);
            count++;
        }
        else if(paramaters[index] is String){ }.... // Thats just one thing i wanna    use.. i've got more
        ..........
        ..........
    }
return ReadInt32(0x000000);
}
```

so i need to figure out what type the parameter is + i wanna use an unknown amount of arguments and i have no idea how i would do this xD

I hope its clear and hopefully someone can Help me :3
Thx, Nico!

Comment: Is C++11 allowed? If so - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic

Comment: Have you considered a variadic template?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, Wrong link; that's the old way.

Comment: @chris oh wow, good catch. Was supposed to be a second link "if you're bound not to use C++11 then you can still do.." but I decided to drop that. Ended up doing the wrong thing on both ends. Here is the correct link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn439779.aspx

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, Here's another: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve something similar in C++ with variadic templates. Note that since C++ has no runtime reflection, it's not possible to dynamically get the type of any value: it can only be done at compile-time. **Importantly**, this also means that you **cannot** build a parameter list at runtime and pass it to the function without rolling out your own stuff to do it.

It is also arguably much more complicated than a C# equivalent (but then again, if C++ had all the strengths of C# with no weaknesses of itself, nobody would be using C#).

There may be other patterns, but the one I usually use looks like this (example with a print function):

```
template<typename... T>
void print_all_values(int value, T... values)
{
    printf("%i ", value);
    print_all_values(values...);
}

template<typename... T>
void print_all_values(double value, T... values)
{
    printf("%g ", value);
    print_all_values(values...);
}

template<typename... T>
void print_all_values(const char* value, T... values)
{
    printf("%s ", value);
    print_all_values(values...);
}

template<typename Unknown, typename... T>
void print_all_values(Unknown&& value, T... values)
{
    printf("(can't print) ");
    print_all_values(values...);
}

void print_all_values() {}

print_all_values(4, "hello world", 5.2, nullptr);
// prints: "4 hello world 5.2 (can't print)"
```

What happens here:

```
template<typename... T>
void print_all_values
```

This tells the compiler to create a distinct version of `print_all_values` for each different parameter type sequences it finds in my program.

```
void print_all_values(int value, T... values)
void print_all_values(double value, T... values)
void print_all_values(const char* value, T... values)
```

These differentiate the call per the first parameter. The idea here is that the function will only print its first parameter, then recursively call the template version with the remaining parameters:

```
{
    printf("%s ", value);
    print_all_values(values...);
}
```

At the end of the recursion chain, each parameter has been printed.

For my example `print_all_values(4, "hello world", 5.2, nullptr)`, this is basically what would happen:

- `print_all_values(4, "hello world", 5.2, nullptr)` -> the compiler uses `print_all_values(4, ...)`, at runtime it'll do `printf("%i", value)`, and the call at the end of the function becomes:
- `print_all_values("hello world", 5.2, nullptr)` -> the compiler uses `print_all_values("hello world", ...)`, at runtime it'll do `printf("%s", value)`, and then:
- `print_all_values(5.2, nullptr)` -> the compiler uses `print_all_values(5.2, ...)`, `printf("%g", value)`, then:
- `print_all_values(5.2, nullptr)` -> the compiler can't find a suitable overload, so it falls back to the `print_all_values(Unknown&& value, T... values)` overload, does "(can't print)", and creates a call to `print_all_values()`, which does nothing.

The last overload:

```
template<typename Unknown, typename... T>
void print_all_values(Unknown&& value, T... values)
```

tells the compiler how handle any unknown type (in this case by printing `(can't print)`). Without this overload, we'd get a compile-time error if we tried to print an unknown type (because it all happens at compile-time, remember).

Comment: What about `dynamic_cast<>` and `typeid` ? Other than that the answer seems good.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, they only work for types with a vtable, so you can't use them for integral types (which is what OP has as an example).

Comment: Your answer (and I quote) says " it's impossible to dynamically get the type of an object: it can only be done at compile-time." - That was not to dispute the general tone of your answer but to note that that specific part of it is not (generally) correct. It _is_ possible to dynamically get the type of an object in some cases.

Comment: Yes, I just rephrased it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try a variadic template declaration like given in the following sample?

```
template<typename... Args>
static int32_t Procedure(uint32_t address, Args&&... parameters) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Note you have not expanded the variadic pack

Comment: @rightfold THX a lot for improvements (I'm still not really familiar with this stuff)!

Comment: Thanks alot for this but how would i know what datatype a paramter has

Comment: @user3529541 Forward `parameters` to known (also variadic) functions, or unpack the parameters list by using specializations.

Answer (score 0):

C++ allows you to write functions accepting any number of parameters in the form of variadic template functions:

```
template<typename... ARGS>
void f( ARGS... args )
{

}
```

In that example, `ARGS` and `args` denote what is known as `variadic packs`. Neither are a template parameter or an function parameter, are just something that represents **a set of template parameters, and a set of function parameters (Respectively)**.

So that are not parameters, are parameter packs, and then **them cannot be manipulated directly**. To use the content of a variadic pack, **you have to expand the pack with an ellipsis**.
Consider the example above: `template<typename... ARGS>` declares a variadic template with a variadic-pack named `ARGS` which represents a set of type template parameters.
In the next line, we expand that pack (`ARGS...`) to use that types as the types of the function argumments. That generates the variadic pack of function argumments `args`.

To use that argumments inside the function, you should expand `args` too. Since a pack is just a indetermined set of argumments, **you can only use it in contexts where you use the hole set of argumments**, in other words, you cannot access directly an specific element of the pack. For example:

```
template<typename... ARGS>
void f( ARGS... args )
{
    f( args... ); //We call f() expanding the args pack of function parameters
                  //and passing the set of parameters to the function.
}
```

If you need to traverse the set of parameters in a pack (Which you would do in C# using the subscript operator on the params), you have to use the functional programming way of pattern matching and head-tail recursive list traversing:

```
template<typename HEAD , typename... TAIL>
void print( const HEAD& head , const TAIL&... tail )
{
    std::cout << head << std::endl; //Do something with the head (Which is a 
                                    //normal function parameter)

    print( tail... ); //Pass the tail to the next call
}
```

Note that function expects at least one parameter (A variadic template could be empty, but `print()` has one non-variadic parameter) . You should provide an overload with no parameters to act as base case (The case when there is no more argumments in the argumments list):

```
void print()
{
    //Base case. Does nothing.
}
```

Now consider the signature of the `print()` function: Is a function which can take any number of parameters of any combination of types. In contrast to the C# (And Java) approach, storing the parameters in an array of an universal base class, and rely on polymorphism and casting), the C++ approach uses a  statically-typed alternative, where the type of each function parameter is well determined at compile time.